# Right-aligned navigation bar

Tags: html, css, right-align

Navigation menu doesn't align to the right. Please help!

** HTML code: **

```
<nav id="main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

** CSS code (not working): **

```
nav#main li {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
nav#main {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: How about you use `float:right` on your `nav#main li` if you want it to be right-aligned

Comment: Thank you, but that re-orders the list (Work / About / Contact) becomes (Contact / About / Work), instead of moving it to the right.

Comment: are you using bootstrap?.

Comment: Nope, just plain old HTML5 & CSS3, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a width to your nav item or setting it's display property to inline block. It's a block level element so by default it takes all the horizontal space that there's available. So if it's 100% wide you can't see where it's aligned/floated.

```
nav#main {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
nav#main {
   width: 50% /*for example*/
}
```

Comment: Forgot a semicolon from the latter option. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you, the 1st suggestion re-orders the list (Work / About / Contact) becomes (Contact / About / Work), instead of moving it to the right.

Comment: 2nd suggestion only makes the distance between the words smaller, but doesn't move the whole thing to the right.

Answer (score 0):

try this you don't need any float ,it works

```
nav#main ul li  {
text-align: right;
text-decoration: none;
display:inline-block;
}

#main{
text-align: right;
 }


<nav id="main">
<ul>
    <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>   
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I still get (Work About Contact) glued to the left side of the screen.